# Print spooler needs monthly restart

Tags: windows, printing, windows-server-2019, print-server

I've got a print server that manages a few printers of the same model.

Every few weeks a printer will refuse to print until the print spooler service is restarted. It doesn't seem to be a problem with the job as it usually prints fine on one of the other printers which are identical and use the same driver.

I can't find anything that tells me why this is happening. The only indication is the queue status turns to "Attention Required".

It usually happens after around a month of uptime, although I've had it work for several months and sometimes it breaks after only a few days.

Is there any way I can prevent this?

Comment: What did the printer manufacturer say about the issue when you asked them?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I've given up trying to get anything useful out of the manufacturer a long time ago. I'll try their distributor if I can't nail the problem myself as they're often slightly more helpful.